# youtube-dl Process Video Title to String crashes

Tags: c#, wpf, youtube-dl

I'm using Visual Studio 2015, C#, WPF.

I'm trying to run [youtube-dl.exe](https://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/index.html) on a video and capture the title to a `string`.

I run the command through a `using` `Process`. It works when running the `C#` program in `Debug` or `Release` mode through Visual Studio, but crashes only when running the compiled `exe` by itself, outside of Visual Studio.

The `youtube-dl` command also works when copy pasted into `cmd.exe`.

```
 youtube-dl --get-filename -o "%(title)s.mp4" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TWNhqCHw0qc
```

---

```
string title = string.Empty;

using (Process p = new Process())
{
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    p.StartInfo.StandardErrorEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "youtube-dl";
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "--get-filename -o \"%(title)s\" "  + "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TWNhqCHw0qc";

    p.Start();

    var output = new List<string>();
    while (p.StandardOutput.Peek() > -1)
    {
        output.Add(p.StandardOutput.ReadLine());
    }

    title = string.Join("", output);
}

MessageBox.Show(title);
```

Comment: What's the error you get when running your program as a `.exe`?

Comment: @dcg It gives the same result.

Comment: @dcg Do you mean using `youtube-dl.exe` in the arguments? The program freezes up and windows says not responding.

Comment: @dcg I put it inside a try/catch, and the Exception says `System.InvalidOperationException: The Process object must have the UseShellExecute property set to false in order to redirect IO streams.`

Comment: You said your app were not responding. I found [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/057f1444-1dea-4c2f-bb48-612478de0f5c/processstandardoutputread-amp-peek-hang-on-empty-buffer?forum=csharpgeneral) thread. Take a look at it. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, I will look at that. I think I found what is wrong, `youtube-dl` can't run from Program Files because it requires administrator privileges, and also cant use `UseShellExecute`. So I have to relocate the exe.

Comment: @dcg That is odd, is it `youtube-dl` or does that happen with any `exe` when redirecting IO streams from Program Files location?

Comment: Did you test it in a location other than `Program Files` and worked? If so that's odd!

Comment: Yeah, I moved it to Downloads folder and it worked from there.

Answer (score 0):

There is command line option:

```
youtube-dl --encoding UTF8
```

Worked for me!